# Non-reproducible ImportError

Tags: python, importerror

I get an ImportError when I run a script that I can't reproduce in a Python interpreter.

```
$ head -6 bin/taglint
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

import re
from lsaf.lsaf import file_info, error, exit

$ taglint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ernest/bin/taglint", line 5, in <module>
    from lsaf.lsaf import file_info, error, exit
ImportError: No module named lsaf
```

However, the import works fine in an interpreter:

```
$ /usr/bin/env python
Python 2.7.3rc2 (default, Apr 22 2012, 22:30:17) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lsaf.lsaf import file_info, error, exit
>>>
```

What is happening here?

*Additional info:*

```
Python 2.7.3rc2 (default, Apr 22 2012, 22:30:17) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lsaf; print(lsaf)
<module 'lsaf' from '/home/ernest/lib/python/lsaf/__init__.pyc'>
```

The PYTHONPATH environment variable is set to PYTHONPATH=/home/ernest/lib/python.

Comment: It might be an issue with `sys.path` -- where's `lsaf`? Please give the output of `import lsaf; print(lsaf)`.

Comment: You didn't name your script by any chance `lsaf.py`?

Comment: rename it and it will work, your script tries to import itself, but there is no package in `lsaf` in your own script. importception

Comment: @Ernest A, did it work after renaming the script?

Comment: @AlexanderStefanov, yes it did.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with `sys.path`
check your `lsaf`

May beYou didn't name your script by `lsaf.py`

rename it and it will work, your script tries to import itself, but there is no package in `lsaf` in your own script. importception